# How to toggle div visibility using radio buttons with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I know there are many other posts on here with similar questions, but I can find one related to multiple radio buttons used to toggle visibility on a single page.

I have a set of 20 questions on my form, and when the user selects "Yes", I'd like a textarea to display for that particular question so they can enter a description.

I previously ran into an issue where selecting the "Yes" radio button would toggle the visibility of all textareas on the page, but have tried to get around that with `parent().find('.toggle')`, but it still doesn't seem to be working.

Any help you could provide would be great!

Javascript:

```
$('.toggle').hide();

$('.show').bind('change',function(){

    var showOrHide = ($(this).val() == 1) ? true : false;

    showOrHide.parent().find('.toggle').toggle(showOrHide);

})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="question">
    <label>Question 1</label>
    <span class="options"> 
        No <input type="radio" class="show" value="0" id="question_1_no" name="question_1">
        Yes <input type="radio" class="show" value="1" id="question_1_yes" name="question_1">
        <br />
        <textarea class="toggle" name="question_1_details" id="question_1_details"></textarea>
    </span> 
</div>

<div class="question">
    <label>Question 2</label>
    <span class="options"> 
        No <input type="radio" class="show" value="0" id="question_2_no" name="question_2">
        Yes <input type="radio" class="show" value="1" id="question_2_yes" name="question_2">
        <br />
        <textarea class="toggle" name="question_1_details" id="question_1_details"></textarea>
    </span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following line you assign either `true` or `false` to the `showOrHide` variable:

```
var showOrHide = ($(this).val() == 1) ? true : false;
```

You then attempt to call a jQuery method on that boolean literal, and obviously that won't work. Use `this` again instead. You could also use `siblings` instead of climbing up a level:

```
$(this).siblings('.toggle').toggle(showOrHide);
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/LN5xu/).

On a separate note, you could simplify your code a bit, because `0` and `1` will coerce to `false` and `true`, so you don't need your conditional statement:

```
$('.show').bind('change',function() {
    $(this).siblings('.toggle').toggle($(this).val());
});
```

Also, if you're using the latest version of jQuery (1.7) you should use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `bind`.

Comment: Just realized that the last change you mentioned doesn't quite work.  See http://jsfiddle.net/LN5xu/2/.  It displays the details no matter what you select first (i.e. if you select "No", it will display the details).